# Word vectorization for neural network input?

Tags: java, nlp, neural-network

I wanted to try some NLP things on a Neural-Network, but for the input I need vectors of word, "one-of-k" can't be used because of the big vocabulary. So I tried to do "multidimensional scaling",which for reasons unknown to me doesn't work. "Programming Collective Intelligence" was the book that I followed for this.

This isn't actually my Problem on which I wanted to work on. So if there would be a library available which will do this work, I could overcome this obstacle and experiment on my actual problem.

Comment: maybe you should give an example. Given some documents, what are the vectors input you need before feeding it into the neural network?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/) and try the api's from it. Although, I must accept I have not clearly understood the question.